# substitute system.reflection for "this"

Tags: c#, this, system.reflection

I have a method I am trying to make a little more easy to widely deploy.

```
NHibernateISession.log4netLogFileEntry("DEBUG", "hello",
    System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName);
```

I would like to reduce the `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName` to a simple `this`.

But how do I get the `FullName` from `this.FullName`?

Just fyi in case it helps you:
`System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName` gives you the

```
<namespace>.<namespace>.<namespace>.<class>
```

Comment: What does `this` have to do with `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName`?

Comment: You mean `this.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: Convert NHibernateISession.log4netLogFileEntry("DEBUG", "hello", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName);   - to - NHibernateISession.log4netLogFileEntry("DEBUG", "hello", this);

Comment: @DStanley That's not the same at all - if you're in a derived class, you'll get the name of the derived class even if it hasn't overriden the method in question.

Comment: @Luaan I realize that, but it seems to be what the OP is looking for (right or wrong).

Comment: `Environment.StackTrace` will also give you what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Exception.StackTrace is an excellent substitute for what I was attempting.
In fact, it is even better.
And all I have to do is:
    try { ... } catch (Exception e) { myfunction(e); }
and:
    MyFunction(Exception e) { log(e.StackTrace) }

Answer (score 3):

`this` is an object - `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` is a type.  If you want to get the full name of the type of `this` then use

```
this.GetType().FullName
```

But note that they aren't equivalent.  The longer one returns the type that *declares* the method.  If the actual object is a subclass then you'll get the sub-type name.  It also won't work for `static` methods, while `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` would.

If you actually want the type that declares the method in question then

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

is the correct approach.  There is no keyword or shortcut that can be used in its place generically.

Comment: Correct. I what the type that declares the method. I don't want the object itself.  I probably can't use 'this'.  But is there a super simple reference that I can use as universally as I can use 'this' (if I were only interested in the instance of the class (the object)?

Comment: @user2367083 No, there's no keyword or shortcut to define that. You could use `nameof` but you'd have to insert the name of the class and/or method - there's no way to generically extract the declaring type.

Comment: The is there a way that the called method can know/derive the context of the calling method (without the calling method sending the called class it's information)?  ((( I'm assuming there isn't )))

Comment: Yes - and you're already using that method.  I'm not sure what the problem is other than wanting to reduce an already fairly simple line.

Comment: Well It is a lot easier to remember to use (and to train others) "this" instead of "blablablablablabla..."

Comment: You can always submit a feature suggestion on http://connect.microsoft.com if you feel like is a feature that is highly valuable.